# Initially, I would just like to be pointed in the right direction on this problem involving combinations (I think).

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I want to select individuals to create a musical ensemble consisting of 1 each violin, harp, oboe, and kazoo.  I have 4 groups of experienced candidates (with varying quantities of members).  Each single group of candidates has the relevant experience for one instrument.  HOWEVER, these subsets are OVERLAPPING, in that some individuals belong to 2 or more groups.  I obviously do not want to choose the same Joe Schmoe to play both the harp and the violin.  Ultimately, I need to calculate the number of possible UNIQUE combinations (permutations?).  I don't know how to answer the question "does order matter" - only to the extent that I do not generally want to choose a person to play the harp from the group of past oboe players (unless they are one of those overlappers).  And I cannot have any single individual repeated in a given combination of 4.

If I can just be pointed in the right direction, I might be able to figure it out from there.  I am hoping to implement my final solution somehow in Excel, if that matters to your answer.  Thx in advance.